# How to disable function keys

Tags: function-keys

I want to create a live version of Ubuntu where the user does not have access to function keys, meaning that they do not produce any effect when pressed. How can this be automated from booting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you just make your USB using [USB Universal Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and you are given an option to "Make the Drive Persistent", Check Box, yes, and make the disk.

Second, load up the instance, and for remapping keys you need two tools, xev  and xmodmap.

Start terminal and run xev.

If the key you are mapping has a different meaning when used with the Shift key (for example for British keyboard layouts, Shift+2 gives quotation marks) then you can simply list the secondary command after the first. For example if you want the key with code 53 to map to backslash normally, but to the bar symbol when used with shift, you might do:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = backslash bar"

xmodmap -pke >~/.Xmodmap
```

(it creates a file named .Xmodmap in your home directory (~))

Then you have to create a file named .xinitrc in your home directory where you put command xmodmap .Xmodmap in.

You can now modify .Xmodmap and run xmodmap .Xmodmap from console to see the changes.

source: Ubuntu Foruns